# font-weight not working in firefox?

Tags: jquery, css

I was dynamically creating divs and found that some properties in the style are not working in firefox

```
$(".contacttiles").eq(i).append("<div id=mm"+i+"' class=exp style='font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;color:#FFFFFF;margin-left:3px;width:120px;height:120px;position:relative;word-wrap: break-word;left:0;top:0'>"+position+"</div>");
```

The font-size,font-weight are not working in firefox. But  when I load the same page in chrome it works. I googled and found that font-weight is supported in firefox. I added the font-weight and size property with the help of firebug ,then it showed properly in firefox. But when I add those things in the style property in the source code , it is not showing.
Is it because I am dynamically creating div or is there some other property for firefox?

Comment: Could you post a minimal example of your problem on http://jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be missing opening apostrophe in

```
"<div id=mm"+.....
```

Should be

```
"<div id='mm"+.....
```